# ASPNET Core API with api-key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am developing an easy API with ASP.NET Core (2.2). The API is getting some values with POST, does some calculations and returns a double array.

The API should just be available for 2-3 servers.
What would be the best approach for authentication? I was thinking that I just give every server a Key, which they have to send in every request and simply ask in the controller, if the key is valid (and maybe checking the ip-address).

Is that the right approach or should I implement a filter (which looks more time-consuming)?

```
[HttpPost]
public outputModel Post([FromBody] inputmodel input)
        {
            double[] dbldummy = new double[115];

            if (!input.apikey=="12345")
            {
                return null;
            }
            //do some calculations and fill otp

            return otp;

        }
```

Comment: thats a Valid Idea, 
Let them send the Key in the header and u filter it before the Controller using action filters. 

Ref to action filters:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_action_filters

Comment: Unfortunately authentication is more complicated than this and is usually closely related to the user (person) using the API. This would usually require them to login to the application in some way.

Comment: A token based way is usually the way to go. However for non-critical APIs manually placing a private key on both servers, and sending public keys would be a more practical solution, as long as the connection is secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create Authentication middle ware class which will do basic authentication that you need to pass in your API Call

add following class in API project

```
  public class AuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        //IConfiguration _ic;
        public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //string dbConn2 = configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettings:DbConnection");
            string AuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["AuthKey"];
            string AuthPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["AuthPass"];

            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Extract credentials
                    string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                    string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));
                    int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');
                    var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
                    var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

                    //string username1 = Encryption.Encrypt("test", username);
                    //string password1 = Encryption.Encrypt("test", password);
                    if (username == AuthKey && password == AuthPass)
                    {
                        await _next.Invoke(context);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic realm=\"ABCProject\"";
                // no authorization header
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

in startup.cs add following code which will bind above class with the application

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");

                       app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

all the requests will be redirected to this class and will check if the request contains specific Authorization header or not if it contains then it will give the OP if it is not contains the header it will through 401 unauthorized status code

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! But which benefits does this have in my specific example? Are there any security issues on my example, or why should I do this?

Comment: what you have done is sending the key in post param but by this way you will send the key in the header value by which 2 request will be sent to the API 1st will be the authorization request if the 1st request is validated then only the actual api request will be sent to the API, also with little changes in this code ,you can also check domain header and white list what domains are allowed to access the API

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will use your solution.